# File Permission as MSI self-healing feature

Tags: wix, windows-installer, file-permissions

On Windows, when a program installed via MSI is run through an advertised shortcut, it checks that all the installed features exist and runs self-healing/auto-repair to replace missing ones.

Is it possible to set a file's ACL as a feature on install that will be self-healed if the ACL is wrong?  If it matters, the file in question

1. is not installed by our MSI
2. may not exist (not existing is OK, so long as it has the proper permission if it exists)

I'm currently using WiX to build my installers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; ACLs aren't resources that MSI uses to validate health. Even if they were, it would likely be tied to a file anyway.

If it's that important, you should check the ACL when your app starts.